# Как вывести посты по id категории для пользовательской таксономии

Tags: php, wordpress

Проблема: не могу вывести посты из определенной категории, для пользовательской таксономии.

```
$args  = array(
        'post_type'        => 'portfolio', 
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'cat' => 26,
      );
      $projects = new WP_Query( $args )
```

Comment: Опять закрыватели в деле. Не знаете, что такое таксономия - сходите в гугл, поднимите вой уровень образования. Не закрывайте вопросы, которых не понимаете в силу недостатка знаний о WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключевое слово `cat` работает только для стандартной таксономии Рубрика. Иными словами, для категорий обычных записей WordPress. Для пользовательский таксономий нужно указать название таксономии (допустим, `project_type`) и термин таксономии (допустим, `house`):

```
$args     = array(
    'post_type'      => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'project_type'   => 'house',
);
$projects = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказку